# How do I split apart a database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, database-project

I've got three database projects. I'd like to have the base project contain common tables and other common objects. And then, I'd like to have the other two projects contain version specific objects that will work with different versions of an application, in other words, depending on the version of the application I will be interfacing with I will be deploying either one database project or the other.

I thought that if I just made a reference to the base database project in the two  version specific databases and then instructed each of the database projects to deploy to the same database it would just work but apparently I'm missing something. When I try to deploy a version of the database it says it can't find any the objects that are referenced in the dependent database project.

The projects build fine, a deployment script just won't generate for the dependent database. It says that objects which are referenced in the base project do not exist.

I'm trying to do this with visual studio 2008 database edition gdr 2 to a 2008 database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if I set the project to deploy the base database project script it works fine. Guess I have to always deploy the script. I'd prefer to not to have to do that though.